# Run an exe file with .net with arguments and taking the output

Tags: c#, .net, process

the exe file is very simple it just takes one argument and reverse it and show the result and i want to intergate that into my web app . I use System.Diagnostics.Process and i can't simply put a number and take the reversed number .
this is the code i curenlty use but the output is always 0

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                 process.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/reverse.exe");
                 process.StartInfo.Arguments = UI.UserInput;
                 process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                 process.Start();

                 StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                 StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

                 using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
                 using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
                 {
                     process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
                         if (e.Data == null)
                         {
                             outputWaitHandle.Set();
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             output.AppendLine(e.Data);
                             
                         }
                     };
                     process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                     {
                         if (e.Data == null)
                         {
                             errorWaitHandle.Set();
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             error.AppendLine(e.Data);
                         }
                     };

                    

                     process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                     process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    UI.Output = output.ToString();
```

And this is the pyhton file that i made the exe

```
_rev=0
while(user_input>0):
  dig=user_input%10
  _rev=_rev*10+dig
  user_input=user_input//10
print(_rev)
```

Comment: You have to wait for the process to end before you examine the output.

Comment: so should i use process.close and then take the output?

Comment: No, call `process.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: when i do that it's getting stuck there and nothing happens

Comment: You are aware that the python program you're calling waits for an user input? `process.WaitForExit()` will only return when your program ends.